# Python Scikit-Learn SVM - No Predicted Samples for a Class

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am doing a classification task in Python to classify audio files of different musical instrument into their respective class, in my case there are 4 class, which are Brass, String, Percussion, and Woodwind. I used SVM algorithm as the classifier. My code looks a bit like this (I do not change any parameter for the classifier):

```
#X is feature matrix, y is class vector
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

#SVM Classifier
svm = SVC()
svm.fit(X_train,y_train)
svm_pred = svm.predict(X_test)
print(metrics.classification_report(y_test,svm_pred)
```

When I try to run this code, I got problem with the classifier. The error code looks like this:

```
            precision  recall   f1-score   support

Brass         1.00      0.21      0.34        72
Percussion    0.38      1.00      0.55       279
String        1.00      0.15      0.26       276
Woodwind      0.00      0.00      0.00       156

avg / total   0.58      0.43      0.32       783

C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1135: UndefinedMetricWarning: Precision and F-score are ill-defined and being set to 0.0 in labels with no predicted samples.
```

When I checked my predicted labels from SVM classifier(svm_pred), no Woodwind class are predicted by the classifier

```
>>> set(svm_pred)
{'Brass','String','Percussion'}
```

> My number of samples for each class are like this: Brass = 200 samples, Woodwind = 500 samples, Percussion = 900 samples, and String = 800 samples so it is a bit imbalanced

My question is, is it possible for a SVM classifier to not predict a class at all in the output of the classifier like my case above?

Comment: Have you noticed that you are using knn.predict() in your code instead of svm.predict()?

Comment: Sorry, that was typo. I have used the correct one ( svm.predict() ) in my real program and still got the results above. @KRKirov

Comment: If Woodwind is as well represented in the training set as in the testing set, my guess would be that your model is completely off and therefore does not predict this class. Try scaling of any numerical features using sklearns scale() http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html  and the different kernel options of the SVM classifier http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html .

Comment: I tried using Polynomial kernel in the parameter and it gives a significant better result (>90% accuracy). The default kernel from SVC() function is RBF. How can I analyze why this happened? @KRKirov

Comment: Add the scaling as well - it is bound to help you further.

Comment: What is the difference if I use StandardScaler() or MinMaxScaler()? @KRKirov

Comment: Please read the sklearn documentation in order to figure this out. By the wa, since it has helped you I am going to move my previous comment to an official answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your answer. It helps a lot @KRKirov

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Another problem might be due to the fact that if you do not stratify while splitting your dataset, it might be that some of the folds do not contain one class at all, while others do. Try using the option stratify=y to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

If Woodwind is as well represented in the training set as in the testing set, my guess would be that your model is completely off and therefore does not predict this class. Try scaling of any numerical features using sklearns scale()

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html

and the different kernel options of the SVM classifier

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html